# General Question: How Do I Retrieve Data from Amazon AWS DynamoDB to Salesforce?

Tags: amazon-web-services, salesforce, amazon-dynamodb, apex, apex-code

Currently, I have one custom object in Salesforce, and one of its field value is stored in a DynamoDB table.

This table is pretty simple. it only contains two columns, the unique id of the custom object and the field value.

Could anyone tell me how I can retrieve the field value for the custom object on Salesforce side? Do I need to use any connector, API calls, or something else?

Thanks